# Intellij Idea Ultimate Tomcat 7 not starting my project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, grails

I have resolved all issues of the Groovy on grails project but the project is not starting in my intellij idea.

This is the error I am stuck at for 3 days now.

The project runs fine with `grails run-app` command on port `8080`
I am using grails 2.4.4, tomcat 7 because the project is an old project, java 1.7 because 2.4.4 grails works best with 1.7 jdk and sdkman to manage my java configurations over a macos 12.4

````
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.......................................................     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/paradox/Developer/contractualprojects/yoska/kona-coach/target/work
..
|Running Grails application
Error |
2022-06-05 16:36:46,385 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR core.ContainerBase  - A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kona-coach]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kona-coach]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1268)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Error |
Server failed to start: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Comment: Can you post the entire console output,  there maybe a clue in the way java is being called and the parameters being passed to it.

Comment: sure, here you go. https://pastebin.com/85qEXSVi

Comment: "This is the error I am stuck at for 3 days now." - I am really sorry to hear that.  If the app can be run with `run-app` it can definitely be run with IntelliJ.  Looking at the environment would make this easy to troubleshoot.  If you fill out the form at https://grails.org/support.html for a free consultation we can schedule a call to look at a screenshare and straighten it out. Sorry for the trouble, and let us know if we can help. Best of luck!

Comment: Sure, Thank you for the response. I have filled the form for the consultation call. Awaiting for the response from your team.